# Bootstrap Stretch col Height upto Parent DIV Height

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, height

Here's the code I'm using:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-2 text-center align-self-center mh-100" style="background-color:red;">
30% Off
</div>
<div class="col-md-8">
<span class="badge badge-default">Promo Code</span>
<h3 style="font-size:20px;font-weight:700;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h3>
<p style="font-size:12px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <strong>consectetur adipiscing elit</strong>. Aliquam eget sapien sapien. Curabitur in metus urna. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Phasellus eu sem sapien, sed vestibulum velit. Nam purus nibh, lacinia non faucibus et, pharetra in dolor.</p>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2 text-center align-self-center">
<button class="btn blue-gradient btn-rounded btn-md">Get Code</button>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

It output following screen:

[image]

Issue: The col height doesn't stretch to the parent div. I've set the background to red and it's not stretched upto the parent div height.

I can use the padding property but is there any other way to do that!

Comment: You may wanna look into flexbox https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: I've used it but wasn't able to use it properly to achieve what I've wanted

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
    <style>
        .height-auto {
            background-color: red;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
            color: #FFF;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2 height-auto">
                30% Off
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <span class="badge badge-default">Promo Code</span>
                <h3 style="font-size:20px;font-weight:700;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h3>
                <p style="font-size:12px;">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <strong>consectetur adipiscing elit</strong>.
                    Aliquam eget sapien sapien. Curabitur in metus urna. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Phasellus eu
                    sem sapien, sed vestibulum velit. Nam purus nibh, lacinia non faucibus et, pharetra in dolor.
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <strong>consectetur adipiscing elit</strong>.
                    Aliquam eget sapien sapien. Curabitur in metus urna. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Phasellus eu
                    sem sapien, sed vestibulum velit. Nam purus nibh, lacinia non faucibus et, pharetra in dolor.
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <strong>consectetur adipiscing elit</strong>.
                    Aliquam eget sapien sapien. Curabitur in metus urna. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Phasellus eu
                    sem sapien, sed vestibulum velit. Nam purus nibh, lacinia non faucibus et, pharetra in dolor.
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <strong>consectetur adipiscing elit</strong>.
                    Aliquam eget sapien sapien. Curabitur in metus urna. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Phasellus eu
                    sem sapien, sed vestibulum velit. Nam purus nibh, lacinia non faucibus et, pharetra in dolor.
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <strong>consectetur adipiscing elit</strong>.
                    Aliquam eget sapien sapien. Curabitur in metus urna. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Phasellus eu
                    sem sapien, sed vestibulum velit. Nam purus nibh, lacinia non faucibus et, pharetra in dolor.
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <strong>consectetur adipiscing elit</strong>.
                    Aliquam eget sapien sapien. Curabitur in metus urna. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Phasellus eu
                    sem sapien, sed vestibulum velit. Nam purus nibh, lacinia non faucibus et, pharetra in dolor.
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 text-center align-self-center">
                <button class="btn blue-gradient btn-rounded btn-md">Get Code</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Never just post code, please also explain how your code solves the problem the user had.

Comment: Please check the [community guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

All You Have To Do is, Set the Parent Row Height (Eg:- 300px) and Set the Child Height to 100%. It will work!!

Reply If it Doesn't Work!

Eg:-

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row" style="height: 300px">
<div class="col-md-2 text-center align-self-center mh-100" style="background-color:red; height: 100%;">
30% Off
</div>
<div class="col-md-8">
<span class="badge badge-default">Promo Code</span>
<h3 style="font-size:20px;font-weight:700;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h3>
<p style="font-size:12px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <strong>consectetur adipiscing elit</strong>. Aliquam eget sapien sapien. Curabitur in metus urna. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Phasellus eu sem sapien, sed vestibulum velit. Nam purus nibh, lacinia non faucibus et, pharetra in dolor.</p>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2 text-center align-self-center">
<button class="btn blue-gradient btn-rounded btn-md">Get Code</button>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```